# Why is my SqlDependency not firing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sqldependency

I have a database running on MS SQL Server 2005 and an ASP.NET 3.5 web application.

The database contains a product catalog which I'm using to feed "pages" into a CMS running in the web app. Once the pages have been created the application caches them so I need to notify the application of this change so it can recreate the page objects.

The CMS uses it's own caching so an SqlCacheDependency cannot be used to perform this task.

When I fire the app up I do get a subscriber appearing in the result of

```
select * from sys.dm_qn_subscriptions
```

But as soon as I add some data to the table, the subscriber disappears and the OnChanged event never fires.

In my startup code I have the following

```
// Ensure the database is setup for notifications
SqlCacheDependencyAdmin.EnableNotifications(DataHelper.ConnectionString);
SqlCacheDependencyAdmin.EnableTableForNotifications(DataHelper.ConnectionString, "Category");
SqlCacheDependencyAdmin.EnableTableForNotifications(DataHelper.ConnectionString, "Product");

if (!SqlDependency.Start(DataHelper.ConnectionString, SqlDependencyQueueName))
     throw new Exception("Something went wrong");

string queueOptions = string.Format("service = {0}", SqlDependencyQueueName);
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(DataHelper.ConnectionString))
{
     connection.Open();
     using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [CategoryID],[Name]
                   FROM [dbo].[Category]", connection))
     {
           // Create a dependency and associate it with the SqlCommand.
           dependency = new SqlDependency(command, queueOptions, 0);

            // Subscribe to the SqlDependency event.
            dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange);

            command.ExecuteReader().Close();
        }
    }

// ...

void OnDependencyChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    Debugger.Break(); // This never hits
    this.ReloadData();
}
```

Comment: btw, you should always inspect the SqlNotificationEventArg members before reloading data. Otherwise you run the risk of deploying in production a tight loop that reloads on every bad statement or incrrect settings notification. And is better to just invalidate the cache and let the next access load the data, rather than proactively reloading on notification (for the same reasons of avoiding a bad situation where it loops tightly).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check your database `sys.transmission_queue`. Most likely your notification(s) will be there, retained because they cannot be delivered. The `transmission_status` will have an explanation why is this happening. For a more detailed troubleshooting guide, see [Troubleshooting Dialogs](http://rusanu.com/2005/12/20/troubleshooting-dialogs/).

The most often issue is due to EXECUTE AS infrastructure requirements not being satisfied by an orphaned database dbo ownership and can be resolved via:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::<dbname> TO [sa];
```

however the solution depends from case to case, depending on the actual problem, as investigated above.

Answer (score 0):

Your Select is wrong. You must explicity state the Query.
From Microsoft SQL Docs:

> The projected columns in the SELECT statement must be explicitly stated, and table names must be qualified with two-part names. Notice that this means that all tables referenced in the statement must be in the same database.

Comment: The sample the author gave does have a proper SQL query with explicit column names and the two-part name of the table: 
`SELECT [CategoryID],[Name] FROM [dbo].[Category]`